# .NET console app performance - 32 vs 64 bit windows

Tags: .net, performance, x86, 64-bit

This may be trivial, but why does a .NET console app performs more than two times faster on a 32 bit Windows Server when compared to a 64 bit Windows Server? It's the exact same application code, but compiled for different platforms.

Update - application details. It's a C# solution, encompassing one console application and multiple class libraries. The console app is both CPU and memory intensive, it processes multiple lists and arrays. A subtask from the app takes about 10 minutes to complete on a 64 bit Windows Server 2008, whereas on a 32 Windows Server 2008 it lasts less than 5 minutes. Both machines have 16 GB RAM and 2.67 GHz processors.

Comment: Absolutely impossible to say without in depth knowledge of what the program is, and the environments under which it runs.

Comment: This can have many reasons and it is impossible to give an 100% detailled answer without more background information.

It may be that your benchmarks are simply [influenced](http://tech.pro/ericlippert) by the JITer, because your application runs in debug mode or you did not initialize them correctly. 

It may also be that this is a side effect of caching through the WoW64, as described in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx).

Comment: Stab in the dark here, but is the 64-bit OS running on an exotic processor which does not have native 32-bit support? E.g. Itanium? Otherwise, your 32-bit code should run natively even in a 64-bit environment. Most apps we use these days are still 32-bit despite 64-bit having been around for some time now, so if there was a performance issue we'd all be having it.